# extract info from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a string that looks like the following:

```
string foo ="<add key="key1" Value="val1"/>
    <add key="key2" Value="val2"/>
    <add key="key3" Value="val3"/>"
```

frrom this string i need to loop through and get every key value pair and do something with them.
how can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this actually XML? If so, use an XML parser. If it's a bunch of elements but without one "root" element, you could also add that to the start and end:

```
string xml = "<foo>" + foo + "</foo>";
```

and then use an XML parser.

EDIT: Okay, if it's XML you should *definitely* use an XML parser. Otherwise you could easily run into problems with encoded values etc.

Comment: the string is just a bunch of xml from which i just need to get the keys and values.

Comment: Jon's right using an xml parser is a lot easier than trying to pull the value out on your own. The overhead for using it is minimal and the benefits are huge.

Comment: why use an XML parser, or even worse XLINQ, when you can a few lines of string manipulation can pull them out? and if its XML then in theory the values would be correctly escaped anyway!

Comment: @Darknight: Consider the text `<add key="a&amp;b" value="a/b" />` - your code would give `key:a&amp;b, value:ab`, whereas using an XML API you'd correctly get `key:a&b, value:a/b`.

Comment: Well fair enough you could always 'un-escape' them, that would fix the first case, not sure about the second case i.e. '/'

Answer (score 0):

(1) Remove these chars first: <,/,>"
(2) Split on "="

Please Note, with the code below, play around with the loop values (Index Out of Range.. etc)

**EDIT:**

```
private Dictionary[] ExtractValuePair(string PString) {
    Of;
    String;
    String;
    Dictionary _dc = new Dictionary(Of, String, String);
    string[] _tmpStr;
    PString = PString.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("/", "").Replace('"', "").Replace("add key", "").Replace("Value", "");
    _tmpStr = PString.Split("=");
    int i;
    for (i = 1; (i 
                <= (_tmpStr.Length - 2)); i++) {
        _dc.Add(_tmpStr[i], _tmpStr[(i + 1)]);
    }
    return _dc;
}
```

Comment: As per the comment to my answer: try `<add key="a&amp;b" value="a/b" />` and see what result you get. There are many other examples of brokenness I could give, but that's a start...

Comment: the cases it could brake are: <,>,/,'add key','Value' the angle brackets can be solved because XML encoding would escape them, altering the code to un-escape would be easy. The only problem cases would be then: '/','add key' and 'Value'. a little bit of further coding this could be overcome

Comment: @Darknight: Sounds like an awful lot of work when an XML solution is literally a few lines. You hadn't spotted the previous problems - how convinced are you that you've now worked out everything that could go wrong? How much time are you willing to spend on getting this all to work correctly, just to avoid using the built-in XML library? What benefit are you actually gaining from all this work? Maybe you'd like to implement your own string class as well next?

Comment: lol yes, your probably right, I don't see it as a huge amount of work personally. But thats just me, and yes I do like to implement things from scratch, like what I'm doing now: which is creating a PDF lib of my own.....(even though I'm aware of iTextSharp + a ton of others out there)

Comment: Reinventing the wheel for the sake of learning is a reasonable way to spend time. Reinventing the wheel to try to come up with a *better* wheel is a reasonable way to spend time. I don't think either really applies in this case. I suspect that you couldn't come up with fully tested production-ready code which *always* gets this right in less than an hour - whereas it took about two minutes with LINQ to XML.